# How to get the current component TCM id in workflow?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to get the current component TCM id (component which entered in the workflow) with the VBscript given below, but am not getting the Component TCM id 
(something like `tcm:56-1567`)

I tried to use the below code, it gives the id like `tcm:56-363-131200`

```
processingitem = CurrentWorkItem.ID
```

And tried like the below code, it gives the id like `tcm:56-195-131076`

```
processingitem = CurrentWorkItem.ActivityInstance.ProcessInstance.ID
```

And tried like the below code, it doesnt give anything.

```
processingitem = CurrentWorkItem.GetItem()
processingitem = CurrentWorkItem.GetItem(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be: `CurrentWorkItem.GetItem(2).ID`. What does it return for you?

Comment: CurrentWorkItem.Subject or CurrentWorkItem.Subject.ID is not giving the component TCM id

Comment: I am trying to get workitem from the WF VB Script editor. and Subject returns null

Comment: I thought you are using TOM.NET, or CoreService. Updated my answer. If this doesn't work, please tell us what does it return.